# Why the downvotes? Explanations would be helpful

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a question about my Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange post: [2009 Corolla Center Console Cup Holder Insert won't stay in place](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41173/2009-corolla-center-console-cup-holder-insert-wont-stay-in-place)

My question was voted down twice with no comment as to why. I think it would be very helpful for the poster to better formulate questions if down votes were explained. When resting on the down vote button, there are three possible reasons for the down vote:

1. The question does not show any research effort
2. The question is unclear
3. The question is not useful

It would be very helpful if those voting down my question would at least add a comment explaining why they voted it down. I would gladly edit the question if needed, or move it to a different forum if that's necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, thanks for being on Mechanics.SE to ask and answer questions. We appreciate you being here.

People are going to downvote as they see fit. There is no *rules* or 
*regulations* which say they have to post as to why they downvoted any given post, so you unfortunately cannot expect one.

Just from reading your post, let me see if I can decipher some reasons which may help you going forward.

- First of all, ensure you've read [How to ask a good question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help).
- Next, with the question itself, you really didn't provide a lot of information. You didn't mention how you got the old one out.

  - Was it broken?
  - Was there issues where you couldn't just put the new one in place?
  - Was there just not something there which you were trying to replace?
- You also didn't mention what you've tried to do with the new one to get it to stay. Tell us anything here which might help.
- Pictures are worth a million words. With the advent of digital photography and a smart phone, it's really easy to get something reasonable which may help us to help answer your question.

Like I said, there's nothing which can be done about a downvote. It is completely within a user's right to downvote if they feel so inclined and they have the privilege to do so. Unless the people who downvoted you come on this question and specifically tell you, this is probably the best information you'll likely hear about it.

I hope this doesn't discourage you from asking/answering questions. I sometimes get downvoted as well, most of the time without a comment. It's just one of those things.

Comment: Thank you, Paulster2, for your explanation. I completely agree with what you've said. I often find myself leaving out context, sometimes critical context, even when speaking, so I know that's a flaw in my communication skills.

I didn't include a picture, but I did include a link to the eBay page of the item I purchased; that has a picture.

I will edit my question just for the sake of good practice.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Jono - Don't worry too much about it. Stick around. When you have enough rep, ensure you come by [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) before you ask your next question. We can help you get it framed correctly and ensure you have all the details before you actually post it. You'll need 20 points first before you can post in there, though. We can help you, though!